# How to send response as an array of objects in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection, laravel-filters

I am new to the laravel, i have one requirement to remove duplicate data and remove book item as well for that i wrote filters and unique functions it's working fine but the response is changed, can you please help me without effecting the response i want to perform those two actions.

**SrceenCollection**

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection->map(function ($data) {
                return [
                    'name' => $data->name,
                    'slug' => $data->slug,
                    'position' =>(int) $data->position,
                     'icon' => my_asset($data->icon)
                ];
            })
        ];
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public function homeScreenData()
    {
        $menus = $this->appScreen->query()->where('status_id', 1)->orderBy('position', 'ASC')
            ->when(!hasPermission('report'), function ($query) {
                return $query->where('slug', '!=', 'report');
            })
            ->get();
        // return $menus;

        $data = new ScreenCollection($menus);

        //After writing following code i am getting as objects only

         $data = $data->filter(function($item){
           return $item->name !='book' && $item->name !='pc';
        })->unique('name');
        return $this->responseWithSuccess('App home screen menus', $data, 200);
    }
```

**Expected Response from API**

```
"data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Support",
                "slug": "support",
                "position": 1,
                "icon": "http://hrms.localpublic/uploads/appSettings/icon/support.svg"
            },

            {
                "name": "Support",
                "slug": "support",
                "position": 1,
                "icon": "http://hrms.localpublic/uploads/appSettings/icon/support.svg"
            },
{
                "name": "book",
                "slug": "book",
                "position": 1,
                "icon": ""
            },
]
}
```

**Actual -Response i am getting**

```
 "data": {
        "0": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Support",
            "slug": "support",
            "position": "1",
            "icon": "public/uploads/appSettings/icon/support.svg",
            "status_id": 1,
        },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `->unique('name')` add `->toArray()`.

This will turn `collection` *(an object)* into `array`.

If you need response like `data => data => (array)` then you can simply wrap your response:

```
return $this->responseWithSuccess('App home screen menus', ['data' => $data], 200);
```